# Are there any other standard rates term structure decomposition than PCA?

Tags: interest-rates, pca, term-structure

PCA is sometimes used to estimate components in the rates term structure.

Are there any other standard method discussed in the literature or used in practice, what are their advantages and disadvantages ?

Answer (score 2):

Nelson Siegel seems to be pretty standard too

Comment: Can you give some more details? Like what are the pros and cons vs PCA?

Comment: There are more recent variants of this, all cast in a Kalman framework. The purported benefit is theoretical consistency (at least the later derivatives of the model).

Comment: @user2763361 can you provide a paper/reference or more details?

Comment: I don't know anything about using Nelson Siegel but this appears to be the referenced paper: http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/NelsonSiegel.pdf